# Shell Script cannot find python3.6 interpreter

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a file called `update.sh` which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

python3.6
```

When this file is located in `/bin` directory it works and `python3.6` starts like this:

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But when this file `update.sh` is any other directory like where my other projects files are the same file gives error like this:

```
: not found./update.sh: python3.6
```

And any other commands like `cd`, `ls` also only work in the `/bin` directory and not in any other.

What is wrong and how to fix this?

running `printenv` in my projects folder returns this:

```
NVM_DIR=/home/cosmicsage/.nvm
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
HOSTTYPE=x86_64
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
LANG=C.UTF-8
OLDPWD=/mnt/d/Projects/web-engine
NVM_CD_FLAGS=
USER=cosmicsage
PWD=/mnt/d/Projects/web-engine/.git/hooks
HOME=/home/cosmicsage
NAME=DarkPlayground
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
NVM_BIN=/home/cosmicsage/.nvm/versions/node/v11.7.0/bin
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=cosmicsage
PATH=/home/cosmicsage/.local/bin:/home/cosmicsage/.nvm/versions/node/v11.7.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_1804.2019.522.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/admin/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/snap/bin
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

I've tried setting the `$PATH` variable but I don't think I know how to do it correctly.

I'm also running UBUNTU 18.04 ON WSL.

Even if I change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or other doesn`t solve the problem either.

Comment: Does the command `python3.6` work in the directory where you can't run the `update.sh`?

Comment: @deimos yes it certainly does work

Comment: I run chmod a+x update.sh and then ./update.sh

Comment: Try using the absolute path to python3.6 (e.g. `/usr/bin/python3.6`)

Comment: What does `which python3.6` print when you run it interactively, and what does it print from your script?

Comment: @Andras_Korn output of which python3.6 is /usr/bin/python3.6

Comment: @deimos Tried /usr/bin/python3.6 the output : ": not found./update.sh: /usr/bin/python3.6"

Comment: @CosmicSage please tell more about your system. As I understand, you're using Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10? Is there any other customizations?

Comment: Nothing else. My update.sh file is as I have described above. I also have kali virtual machine and it had the same problem. my python3.6 is in /usr/bin. Nothing fancy @deimos. I have tried all other solutions on this website which are similar

Comment: There has to be something more to it, I just installed Win10 + Ubuntu 18.04 terminal and was not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The format of the error message is odd, with the colon at the start of it. Check that your script file does not have `\r\n` line endings, and if so, fix it.

Comment: Yeah you got that right. In Atom I Changed the file-ending from CRLF(WINDOWS) TO LF(LINUX) and it got executed. Thanks man@glennjackman

Comment: @deimos dude it was the line endings bugging me. Thanks❤

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the line-endings for me

My script looked like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

python3.6
```

On close inspection of this file in the atom text-editor I found the the line-endings to be "CRLF"(WINDOWS)

I Then changed the line-endings to be "LF"(LINUX) AND the script was executed!!!

Conclusion: The error was caused by the line-endings as pointed in the comments by @glennjackman . Change it to LF in atom

[image]